# Textbooks for critical phenomena

Tags: resource-recommendations, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

Which textbook do you suggest for an advanced study of critical phenomena?

Answer (score 1):

The standard books are the 20 volume series

[Phase Transitions and Critical Phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_Transitions_and_Critical_Phenomena)

Edited Domb and  Green (vols. 1-6)
and by  Domb and Lebowitz (vols. 6-20)

Each volume has textbook-level articles by various experts.

20 volumes is a lot of books to read. I'd say that volume 6 is the essential one as it introduces the renormalization group and the connections with field theory and Feynman diagrams. I learned how to think of the RG and how to calculate with it from the chapters  by Ken Wilson and by David Wallace  this volume.

A full listing of the topics in each book is found the Wikipedia site linked on the second line above.